# Slider next and previous images instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, navigation, slider

Can somebody please explain to me why this is not working. I am trying to souce to images in javascript for a slider instead of just using text that used to say previous and next as buttons.

```
options = jQuery.extend({
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    navigation: true,
    easing: '',
    timeout: 5000,
    pause: true,
    pauseOnNavHover: true,
    prevText: img src='arrowleft.png'         used to be         prevText: 'Previous',
    nextText: img src='arrowright.png         used to be         nextText: 'Next',
    css3pieFix: false,
    currentClass: 'current',
    onLoad: function(){},
    onStart: function(){},
    onComplete: function(){}
}, options);
```

I am fairly new to all this so please help

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `prevText` and `nextText` expects a string, but in your case you are providing it as `img src = 'image-name'` which is incorrect in many ways.
If you want to pass the image src instead of text then you should use `img.attr('src')` to get the image source, provided you have image selector in `img` variable. Your javascript breaks on `img src='arrowleft.png'` because of incorrect syntax.
It should be:

```
options = jQuery.extend({
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                navigation: true,
                easing: '',
                timeout: 5000,
                pause: true,
                pauseOnNavHover: true,
                prevText: img.attr('src'),
                nextText: img.attr('src'),
                css3pieFix: false,
                currentClass: 'current',
                onLoad: function () {},
                onStart: function () {},
                onComplete: function () {}
            }, options);
```

**Note**: this will work only if you have the image selector assigned to `img` variable. If `img` is undefined then it will again result in error. That's all I can help you on this issue unless you provide more code.

Comment: Oh ok thank you that is very enlightening, so how do I then define which image it chooses? Thank you so so much

Comment: First you need to find the active/current slide/image and then according to your html you can get the next/previous image element using $('selector').next('img') or $('selector').prev('img') . Once you get the image then you can get the source as well. you can refer http://api.jquery.com/next/ and http://api.jquery.com/prev/ . Also for your case $(this) will be useful. $(this) is the current active element in the function.

Comment: You can also look into the slider's documentation for  getting the current image or slide. There must be a way for it